# Is it possible to add a sub-tab within an already existing tab? PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I made a fairly simply GUI, it has 3 tabs for organization - I can show pictures below.

[image: Showing the General GUI]

As you can see there are 3 main tabs for general organization. However I was wondering if it was possible to add a Sub-Tab to one of the existing ones. For example in `Non-Host` would it be possible to add another tab called `Combat` that only shows once you click into the menu of `Non-Host`?

Sorry if my wording is bad, but essentially what I'm asking is if it's possible to add a tab within another tab, that's only accessible when the parent tab is already open.

Comment: I think it should work. If you are using QtDesigner you can slide widgets into other widgets. If you are building the UI directly with code, playing around with the `parent` attribute of your sub-tab should be sufficient.

Comment: I've been doing it purely through code and a text editor. Also I've already tried doing the `parent` attribute for a few of them, and it doesn't seem to work. Although I'm willing to accept if I did it wrong. My normal tabs are defined as `tabwidget = QTabWidget()` then to add a parent label for customizing other GUI elements I also add `label1 = QLabel('')` so I can without hassle use `parent=label` however if I try to attribute this same process to another tab defined under a different label, it either doesn't show. Or always shows next to the existing tabs.

Comment: If you found an *effective* solution, add an answer providing a *descriptive* solution (eventually including the code to fix the issue). Please don't add a pseudo-solution to a question, nor change the title to [solved], this is not a forum.

Comment: @Guimoute setting the parent alone might not be always effective, and it's usually insufficient: widgets should always be added to a layout that is set on an actual parent (which could be the top level window, or a nested widget that already is placed into a layout). For the *rare* occurrence where layouts must not be used, a widget created with a parent *that has been already shown* must be *explicitly* shown, through `show()` or `setVisible(True)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure the same thing out myself and tried a few things and was able to get it to work.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyAPP(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Test")
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)

    self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

    self.show()

class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    # Initialize tab screen
    self.tabs                = QTabWidget()
    self.connect_tab         = QWidget()
    self.non_host_tab        = QWidget()
    self.non_host_wgt        = QTabWidget()
    self.non_host_combat_tab = QWidget()
    self.non_host_other_tab  = QWidget()
    self.slider_tab          = QWidget()

    # Add tabs
    self.tabs.addTab(self.connect_tab, "Connect")
    self.tabs.addTab(self.non_host_tab, "Non-Host")
    self.tabs.addTab(self.slider_tab, "Slider")

    # Connect Tab
    self.connect_tab.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    # Add whatever you need in the layout here
    self.connect_tab.setLayout(self.connect_tab.layout)

    # Non-Host Widget
    self.non_host_wgt.addTab(self.non_host_combat_tab, "Combat")
    self.non_host_wgt.addTab(self.non_host_other_tab, "Other")

    # Non-Host Combat Tab
    self.non_host_combat_tab.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    # Add whatever you need in the layout here
    self.non_host_combat_tab.setLayout(self.non_host_combat_tab.layout)

    # Non-Host Other Tab
    self.non_host_other_tab.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    # Add whatever you need in the layout here
    self.non_host_other_tab.setLayout(self.non_host_other_tab.layout)

    # Non-Host Tab
    self.non_host_tab.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.non_host_tab.layout.addWidget(self.non_host_wgt)
    self.non_host_tab.setLayout(self.non_host_tab.layout)

    # Slider Tab
    self.slider_tab.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    # Add whatever you need in the layout here
    self.slider_tab.setLayout(self.connect_tab.layout)

    # Add Tabs to main layout
    self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
    self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyAPP()
  sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).